# Firefox Vimperator - how to offset link hints?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I learned how to change the size of hints by modifying fields in the :highlight Hint CSS. I made the hint numbers a bit bigger, and as a result they overlap with the hints they're hinting to. (I'd love to post a picture but apparently I'm not entitled to that luxury yet, so I hope I'm clear enough...)

How can I introduce an offset or some other sort of buffer between the hints and the links themselves?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it’s possible. If you look at how the hints are positioned, they get a CSS of `position: absolute` with fixed, calculated X-Y-coordinates. I don’t think you can add an additional relative offset on top of that.

[image]

Comment: Vimperator does allow arbitrary Javascript snippet execution: it would be convoluted, but it should be possible to bind something to a key that looks up all vimperator hint elements on the page, finds the proximate ones, and adjusts them. Making such logic performant and capable of handling edge cases (e.g. offsetting some hints places a hint over a previously non-overlapped hint, etc) would be somewhat of an involved endeavor, however.